# WPF: Custom window.title

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to dynamically change the Windows.Title property. In short I need the application name to be left alligned and the filename to be centered all in the same line.

```
 <Window.Title>
    <TextBlock> test </TextBlock>
</Window.Title>
```

I tried out for starters with something like this, which apparantly is not allowed. Anyone has an idea?